# Convergence rate of test-statistic to chi-square distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multivariate-analysis, goodness-of-fit, multivariate-normal-distribution, chi-squared-distribution

I know that the to test whether $\Sigma=\Sigma_0$ against $\Sigma\ne\Sigma_0$ for an $n\times p$ data matrix, the test statistic is $np(a-1-\log g)$ where $a$ and $g$ are the AM and GM of the eigen values of $\Sigma_0^{-1}S$, and that this test statistic follows chi square distribution asymptotically as $n\to\infty$ with $\dfrac{p(p+1)}2$ degrees of freedom.

I am confused in whether it converges faster for larger $p$ or smaller $p$?? I am getting larger $p$ by simulating the situation and using histograms, but I am not sure.

Please help.